# Limit switch failure

Tags: furnace

My XL80 trane failure!
Limit switch SWT1258 fails at least twice a year now, first one lasted 10 years and then all replacements only last 3 to 10 months.
Seems the switch is used too much but air flow is OK!
Any ideas?
Jim

Comment: Is the filter clean?

Comment: Do yo have access to a good digital electric meter?